# Can you see if a proccess is_alive, without it joining first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I would like to implement pool on my own, as it does not have a timeout method. Therefore i would like to check, wether a process is running, or finished its code, without having to call join, as that would defeat the purpose right?

so in this case, no more than 4 processes should be running at once

```
processes = []
for index in range(0, 4):
   p = multprocessing.Process(...)
   p.start()
   processes.append(p)

while(true):
   #check if alive, if not, quit and create next process for every process, that is finished
   some_code()
   time.sleep(1)
```

What i have right now:

```
processes = []
for index in range(0, 4):
   p = multprocessing.Process(...)
   p.start()
   processes.append(p)

while(True):
   counter = 0
   for p in processes:
      if not p.is_alive():
         counter++
         p.join()
   for _ in range(0, counter):
      p = multprocessing.Process(...)
      p.start()
      processes.append(p)
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What do you mean? is_alive method doesn't work as intended?

Comment: Just call is_alive without joining.

Comment: I am trying to implement pool(). I need to know in the while(true) loop, if one of them is finished, so i can start the next process. I think join kills the concept, because it waits for the finishing moment for the runnning process, right?

Comment: There is a method `is_alive` in the `Process` object that should work for you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.is_alive

Comment: does my change work? i tried what you suggested

Comment: When `is_alive` is false, `p.join()` would do nothing.

Comment: I tried my code, it actually works pretty well, but my break condition for my infinite loop is broken, i need to fix that